# Is it possible to damage a VFD by raising the anode voltage?

Tags: voltage, vacuum-fluorescent

Is it possible to cause damage to a vacuum fluorescent display by raising the anode/grid voltage above the recommended level (not the filament voltage)?

Comment: Is there anything it is *not* possible to damage by application of *sufficient* voltage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course it is. Assuming you don't cause any actual internal arcing, you'll accelerate the erosion/aging of the phosphors caused by the excess electron energy.